# Passing a 3D array to a function.

Tags: c, character-arrays

I'm having a hard time passing a 3D array to a function.  I've googled it to death and I think I understand but the code crashes with no output when run.  (codeblocks, gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void foo(char (*foo_array_in_foo)[256][256]);
int main()
{
char foo_array[256][256][256];
int line_num = 0;
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    foo(foo_array);
    return 0;
}
void foo(char (*foo_array_in_foo)[256][256])
{
    printf("In foo\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stack overflow

```
256*256*256 = 16777216 bytes > STACK_SIZE
```

that is the reason for the segmentation fault.

If you need such a large ammount of memory you have to use `malloc`.

Comment: That makes sense for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line in `main`

```
char foo_array[256][256][256];
```

That creates a local variable of 16777216 bytes, which overflows the stack. You can correct the problem either by declaring the array `static`

```
static char foo_array[256][256][256];
```

or by allocating memory for the array using `malloc`

```
char (*foo_array)[256][256] = malloc( 256 * 256 * 256 );
if ( foo_array == NULL )
    exit( 1 );      // if malloc fails, panic
```

If you choose `malloc`, remember to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

PS. there's nothing wrong with the declaration of the `foo` function.

Comment: Can you please explain the `malloc`?

Comment: @iharob With a 1D array `char bar[100]` becomes `char *bar = malloc(100)`. With a 2D array `char blah[4][5]` becomes `char (*blah)[5] = malloc( 4 * 5 )`. My answer shows how to declare a pointer to a 3D array, and malloc memory for it.

Comment: One more question, why some people use `exit` on `malloc` failure? it's mostly ms windows programmers I think, but I don't get it, if it failed may be you can retry or do something like notify the user and clean up other resources, which I know will be most likely be cleaned by the OS. But what is the logic behind using `exit`.

Comment: @iharob The key point is that the return value from `malloc` should always be checked, and a return value of `NULL` needs to be handled. Calling `exit(1)` is just the easiest way to demonstrate that point.

Comment: I still think it should be `char (*foo_array)[256][256] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char *))` I might be wrong.

Comment: @iharob On a machine with 32-bit pointers that would allocate 1024 bytes, when in fact the code needs to allocate memory for a 16MB array. You need to review pointers to multi-dimensional arrays.