# Optimizing function speed on 3D array

Tags: arrays, r, performance, function, optimization

I am applying a user-defined function to individual cells of a 3D array.  The contents of each cell are one of the following possibilities, all of which are character vectors because of prior formatting:

```
"N"
"A"
""
"1"
"0"
```

I want to create a new 3D array of the same dimensions, where cells contain either `NA` or a numeric vector containing 1 or 0.  Thus, I wrote a function named `Numericize` and used `aaply` to apply it to the entire array.  However, it takes forever to apply it.

```
Numericize <- function(x){
  if(!is.na(x)){
    x[x=="N"] <- NA; x
    x[x=="A"] <- NA; x
    x[x==""] <- NA; x
    x <- as.integer(x)
  }
  return(x)
}
```

The dimensions original array are 480x866x366.  The function takes forever to apply using the following code:

```
Final.Daily.Array <- aaply(.data = Complete.Daily.Array,
                           .margins = c(1,2,3),
                           .fun = Numericize,
                           .progress = "text")
```

I am unsure if the speed issue comes from an inefficient `Numericize`, an inefficient `aaply`, or something else entirely.  I considered trying to set up parallel computing using the `plyr` package but I wouldn't think that such a simple command would require parallel processing.

On one hand I am concerned that I created a stack overflow for myself (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761051/passing-a-3d-array-to-a-function) for more), but I have applied other functions to similar arrays without problems.

```
ex.array <- array(dim = c(3,3,3))

ex.array[,,1] <- c("N","A","","1","0","N","A","","1")
ex.array[,,2] <- c("0","N","A","","1","0","N","A","")
ex.array[,,3] <- c("1","0","N","A","","1","0","N","A")

desired.array <- array(dim = c(3,3,3))

desired.array[,,1] <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,NA,1)
desired.array[,,2] <- c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
desired.array[,,3] <- c(1,0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA)

ex.array
desired.array
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe just `array(as.numeric(ex.array), dim = dim(ex.array))`, because `identical(array(as.numeric(ex.array), dim = dim(ex.array)), desired.array)` is TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for this elegantly simple answer.  This approach comes with a `warning` that NA values are introduced by coercion but that is to be expected based on what goes in and what is expected to come out.

Comment: jep, I'd ignore that warning (or rather take note of it, because often times it's valuable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a vectorized approach:

```
ex.array[ex.array %in% c("", "N", "A")] <- NA
storage.mode(ex.array) <- "integer"
```

You can simply use the second line and it will introduce NAs by coercion.